# fscanf() match string in C

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I have a file laid out like this:

```
X1034Example
X1234Example2
Y2934Example3
```

and say I have opened that file and loaded it into `*fp`, I now want to match lines like this: "X" followed by 4 digits followed by any string so I assumed that would be something like this:

```
FILE **fp;
if ((*fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to read file: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

int id; char label[64];
fscanf(*fp, "X%4d%s", &id, label)
```

However, this doesn't work properly and for the file specified I tested using this snippet:

```
fscanf(*fp, "X%4d%s", &id, label);
printf("%d\n", id);
printf("%s\n", label);

fscanf(*fp, "X%4d%s", &id, label);
printf("%d\n", id);
printf("%s\n", label);
```

and the output I had was

```
1
Example
1
Example
```

is this just due to the non-deterministic behaviour with pointer or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit 1**

So adding a space before the X fixed the first issue but now I just realised that some of the labels have spaces in.

For example:

```
X1245Example Text Here

fscanf(*fp, " X%4d%s", &id, label);
printf("%d\n", id);
printf("%s\n", label);
```

should produce:

```
1245
Example Text Here
```

Comment: Step 1 when having trouble with `fscanf()` and friends.  Test and report its return value.  E.g. `if (fscanf(*fp, "X%4d%s", &id, label) != 2) Report_Error();`

Comment: What is `fp`? Is it a `FILE **`? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: As a hint about your problem, the `"%s"` format skips (possible) *leading* white-space, not trailing. So think about what each line in the file ends with.

Comment: works fine on my machine when `*fp` is `stdin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this just due to the non-deterministic behaviour with pointer or am I doing something wrong?

`fscanf(*fp, "X%4d%s", &id, label)` does not consume the leftover `'\n'` of the previous line.  See hint: [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644277/fscanf-match-string-in-c/48644353#comment84285190_48644277).  The 2nd `fscanf()` simple failed and did not update `id, label`.  Had code checked the `fscanf()` return value, this could have been caught earlier.

Use `fscanf(*fp, " X%4d%s", &id, label)` (Add space) or better yet, code `fgets()` and then `sscanf()` the line and check the return value of the scan.

```
int id; char label[64];
char buffer[sizeof label * 2];  // form a generous buffer

if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
  if (sscanf(*fp, "X%4d%63s", &id, label) == 2) {
    printf("%d\n", id);
    printf("%s\n", label);
  } else {
    Failed();
  }
}
```

To read the *rest of the line*, instead of `"%s"`, :

```
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
  if (sscanf(*fp, "X%4d%63[^\n]", &id, label) == 2) {
    printf("%d\n", id);
    printf("<%s>\n", label);  // added <> to help denote spaces
```

Comment: And say for example the label string had spaces in it what would one do there? i.e  `X1242Example Number 2`?

Comment: @Ollu_ Comment unclear.  Better to post sample input in the question _and_ its desired outcome.

Comment: Added to bottom of question what I meant